# Generating a base64 encoded hash from CLI to match Java

Tags: java, base64, gnu, sha256

I have a java code base that generates an URL safe base64 encoded hash from a string, and wondering if / how this would be possible with linux command line tools. I'm guessing the problem with what I am doing here is with the character set / encoding or to do with converting the string to a byte array. Java code:

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
byte[] digest = md.digest("testString".getBytes());
// ^^ this is where the difference is?
String b64url = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(digest);
// b64url: Ss8LOdnEdmcJo2ifVTrAGrVQVF_6RUTfwLLOqC-6AqM
```

Command line:

```
echo testString | sha256sum | cut -d" " -f1 | base64
# NDgxOGEyY2JkODYwOTY1NjJkODFmYzIwNmQ3ZTYyNWVlNGFjMTU5MmViNTc0MjQwMDQ4OTIzOTBl
# MDQzZTNlYwo=
```

Is it possible to generate base64 encoded sha256 via cli tools?

Comment: Your first mistake is that you're including a newline character in your string your submitting to sha256sum, use "echo -n" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're base64 encoding a hexadecimal string, not the byte values of the hash, which is the equivalent of:

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
byte[] digest = md.digest("testString".getBytes()); // Missing charset
String hex = Hex.encodeHexString(digest);
String base64 = Base64.encodeBase64(hex.getBytes());
```

Comment: I thought it was to do with that. how would I convert the hex representation to a byte array when i pass it to the b64 encoder?

Comment: Not sure if I will be able to update the Java codebase to hex encode prior to base64 encoding, but at least it matches up now. Thanks David.

Comment: echo -n testString | sha256sum  | cut -d" " -f1  | xargs echo -n | base64   @David - yes, because of restricted access to Java code base. Actually just doing the testing in bash, but will ultimately be in a python script.

Comment: @Brett It's a bit unusual to encode twice.  Shouldn't you be fixing your command line instead?

Comment: I don't have access to the java code base, and trying to work bash / python  to get it to work. I will probably write a java hasher for use with CLI, using the same code base and then pipe to `java Hasher testString`. I think this would be the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a StringBuilder to turn your hex into a meaningful string:

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
byte[] digest = md.digest("testString".getBytes());
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuuilder();
for (byte b : digest) {
    sb.append(Integer.toHexString(b & 0xff));
}
String base64 = Base64.encodeBase64(sb.toString());
```

Combined with not including the newline in the echo command, works here ...